# Feature Importance in Isolation Forest

Tags: random-forest, scikit-learn, outliers, anomaly-detection, isolation-forest

In an unsupervised setting for higher-dimensional data (e.g. 10 variables (numerical and categorical), 5000 samples, ratio of anomalies likely 1% or below but unknown) I am able to fit the isolation forest and retrieve computed anomaly scores (following the [original paper](https://cs.nju.edu.cn/zhouzh/zhouzh.files/publication/icdm08b.pdf) and using the implementation in [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html)). This gives me a ranking of potential anomalies to consider. However, how would I further assess the validity of these flags? How can I understand which feature has contributed to the anomaly score the most? Feature importance techniques usually applied in random forests do not seem to work in case of the isolation forest.

Interested to hear your thoughts.
Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear to me that feature importance is even a meaningful concept for isolation forests. By definition, anomalies are any points abnormally far from most of the data. There are no "most important" features that determine an anomaly, as a point could be far in any direction.

Answer (score 8):

I believe it was not implemented in scikit-learn because in contrast with Random Forest algorithm, Isolation Forest feature to split at each node is selected at random. So it is not possible to have a notion of feature importance similar to RF.

Having said that, If you are very confident about the results of Isolation Forest  classifier and you have a capacity to train another model then you could use the output of Isolation Forest i.e -1/1 values as target-class to train a Random Forest classifier. This will give you feature importance for detecting anomaly.

Please note that I haven't tried this myself, so I can't comment on accuracy of this proposed approach.

Comment: Interesting technique. Any reference where you have seen it used?

Comment: That's a good approach and its being used in many cases. It is similar to fitting a decision tree on cluster labels. In both cases you have to be sure that the model fit well (overfit actually).

Comment: The idea of surrogate models as stated above is interesting and ideal as the last resort but with the latest advancements one might be able to get the feature importance using permutation importance or SHAP as well maybe.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried looking at SHAP statistics as a way of measuring feature importance for your isolation forest exercise? Here's a good explanation of SHAP https://towardsdatascience.com/explain-your-model-with-the-shap-values-bc36aac4de3d and you can build an explainer object with any tree based model. From there you can also look at how your features affect individual predictions.

Comment: As the existing answer notes, Isolation Forests' trees are not standard decision trees, so shap probably won't produce anything useful.

Comment: @BenReiniger I’m unsure what you mean Isolation Forests are not standard decision trees. Like a Random Forest, IF builds a large number of trees and like a Random Forest the Isolation Forest subsamples the feature space and subsequently splits on a random value for a given feature. It does this many times to produce uncorrelated trees and the associated error of a specific tree. Path lengths are measured then split off anomalous from non anomalous data. You can then see which features explain why individual data points are considered anomalous, which can also be aggregated across data points.

Comment: Hrm, you may be right: "explaining" the contribution to the path-length-score should work. (+1) I wonder whether the TreeExplainer will be able to do it, or if you'd need the generic KernelExplainer?  (My original complaint was that everything about a split in an isolation forest is random: the feature as well as the splitting point.  Then there's no information gain or impurity reduction, and there's no target at all, but shap shouldn't care about any of that.)

Comment: Ah, indeed, shap now supports IsolationForest:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/451518/232706 , https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/237 , https://github.com/slundberg/shap/pull/784

Comment: @BenReiniger yes I’ve used it previously and it definitely provides a ton of insight for these unsupervised modeling situations

Answer (score 2):

Briefly reiterating first what others have mentioned, one could use a surrogate model like a BDT that is intentionally overtrained on the output of the isolation forest (instead of using the binary output as Khurram Majeed suggested, you could directly train it on the anomaly score). However, we cannot be sure that the surrogate model is learning the same decision paths as the iForest.

On the other hand, the principle behind SHAP is clearer than any surrogate model used to explain the iForest (another good [explanation](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/shap.html) of SHAP). Perhaps because the BDT is doing a poorer job, I found that the feature importances derived from a surrogate BDT and SHAP agreed only roughly, and sometimes disagreed wildly. Both local and global feature importances were considered in this comparison.

Despite all this the iForest is interpretable if its underlying principle is taken advantage of: that outliers have short decision paths on average over all the trees in the iForest. The features that were cut on in these short paths must be more important than those cut on in long decision paths. So here's what you can do to get feature importances:

1. Determine a threshold for decision path length. The authors of the iForest algorithm recommend from empirical studies a subsampling size of 256 [[ref]](https://cs.nju.edu.cn/zhouzh/zhouzh.files/publication/icdm08b.pdf?q=isolation-forest). This is the number of events (sampled from all the data) that is fed into each tree. If you're using this subsampling size, the trees in the iForest can only grow up to $\log_2 (256) = 8$ nodes in depth. Thus you might choose a path length threshold of 3 or 4.
2. For each event, loop through the trees in the iForest and select paths that are shorter than the threshold path length. In these paths, count which features are being cut at each node, the depth of each node, and the numbers of events split at that node. If you're using sklearn's implementation of the iForest, [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html) script may help you in digging through their tree structure. This plot shows what you should have at this stage.
   [image: Feature counts at cut depth]
3. Now that you have feature counts of all the trees at each cut depth, you can condense these into a final feature ranking. This can be done by assigning weights to each node and adding the counts up. For instance you may want to assign larger weights to feature counts that are cut higher up in the tree (and are thus more responsible in creating a overall shorter decision path), and smaller weights to features cut further down. You can also incorporate the ratio of events split at each node into your weights - if there is a large disparity of events split by a certain cut, then that cut is probably important.

Note that there is a lot of freedom to assign weights here, and it may be that your choices are ad-hoc and dataset dependent. I'm not entirely sure, but this may be the reason that feature importances were not implemented in sklearn's iForest.

Anyway, here's a condensation of the feature counts shown above. I'm using a simple 'geometric weight' of 0.5 - essential the number of counts cut first get no modification, the number of counts counts cut second get halved, and those cut third get quartered.
[image]
As you can see, there are a lot of features that aren't very important to isolate this particular event. Here is the SHAP force plot for this event, nice agreement even with a very simple weight assignment!
[image: SHAP force plot]
I've shown the feature rankings for an individual event, but you can easily get global importances by averaging the feature counts over entire dataset. This way you can drop features that don't contribute much to the iForest classification.

If you're using sklearn or other Python based implementations, the biggest disadvantage to this technique is speed. It takes a while to root through all the trees, and if you're interested in global importances you'll have to loop though all the events as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since a while back one can use SHAP to exlain scikit-learn Isolation Forest models. Example code and output in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/451518/201327).

Answer (score 0):

#### [Interpretable Anomaly Detection with DIFFI: Depth-based Isolation Forest Feature Importance](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.11117)

[image]

In this paper, they proposed model-specific methods (i.e. methods
based on the particular structure of the IF model) to address the mentioned
issues.

Specifically,

- A global interpretability method, called **Depth-based Isolation Forest
  Feature Importance (DIFFI)**, to provide **Global Feature Importances
  (GFIs)** which represents a condensed measure describing the macro behaviour of the **IF** model on training data.
- A local version of the **DIFFI** method, called **Local-DIFFI**, to provide
  **Local Feature Importances (LFIs)** is aimed at interpreting individual predictions made by the **IF** model at test time.
- A simple and effective procedure to perform unsupervised feature selection for Anomaly Detection problems based on the **DIFFI** method.

```
@article{carletti2020interpretable,
  title={Interpretable anomaly detection with diffi: Depth-based feature importance for the isolation forest},
  author={Carletti, Mattia and Terzi, Matteo and Susto, Gian Antonio},
  journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:2007.11117},
  year={2020}
}
 
https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2007.11117
```

Code for the paper "[Interpretable Anomaly Detection with DIFFI: Depth-based Isolation Forest Feature Importance](https://github.com/mattiacarletti/DIFFI)".