# How to get top features that contribute to anomalies in Isolation forest

Tags: machine-learning, anomaly-detection, isolation-forest

I am using Isolation forest for anomaly detection on multidimensional data. The algorithm is detecting anomalous records with good accuracy. Apart from detecting anomalous records I also need to find out which features are contributing the most for a data point to be anomalous. Is there any way we can get this?

Answer (score 9):

[SHAP values](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/7062-a-unified-approach-to-interpreting-model-predictions) and the [shap](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) Python library can be used for this. Shap has built-in support for scikit-learn IsolationForest [since October 2019](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/pull/784).

```
import shap
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest

# Load data and train Anomaly Detector as usual 
X_train, X_test, ...
est = IsolationForest()
est.fit(...)

# Create shap values and plot them
X_explain = X_test
shap_values = shap.TreeExplainer(est).shap_values(X_explain)
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_explain)
```

Here is an example of a plot I did for one IsolationForest model that I had, which was time-series.
[image]

You can also get partial dependence plots for a particular feature,
or a plot showing the feature contributions for a single X instance. Examples for this is given in the shap project README.

Answer (score 0):

One possible describing feature importance in unsupervised outlier detecion is described in [Contextual Outlier Interpretation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10589). Similar as in the [Lime](https://github.com/thomasp85/lime) approach, local linearity is assumed and by sampling a data points around the outlier of interest a classification problem is generated. The authors suggest to apply a SVM with linear kernel and use estimeited weights for feature importance.

Comment: I am wondering if you can use LIME to generate local explanations for each of the identified anomalies in IsolationForest?